# using the same onClick button increment counter up to 2 (range 0-2) and then decrement back to 0 from 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble implementing this logically. My count would decrement and increment by 1 and so I would be stuck at 1, never going back down to zero.

`using react:` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/264072/)

counter goes up from 0 to 2 with onClick();

counter: 0 1 2

clicking on the same onClick() button, counter will decrement from 2 back to 0 on each click.

counter: 2 1 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just count, there is no logical way to determine increment or decrement. You can add a boolean in state track increment vs decrement.

```
onClick(e) {
  let count = this.state.increment ? this.state.count + 1 : this.state.count - 1;

  let increment = this.state.increment;

  if (count === 0) {
    increment = true;
  } else if (count >= 2) {
    increment = false;
  }

  this.setState({
    count,
    increment,
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/264102/

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick(e) {
  let tmp = this.state.count;
  tmp++;
  if(tmp > 2){
    tmp = 0;
  }
  this.setState({
    count: tmp
  })
}
```

It's not best answer I think, but It will inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at this example : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/264096/)

```js
 onClick(e) {


  if(this.state.action == '+') {
     this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  } else {
     this.setState({
       count: this.state.count - 1
     });
  }

  if(this.state.count == 1) {
      if( this.state.action == '+') {

        this.setState({
            action: '-'
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
            action: '+'
        });
      }
  }

}
```